# Finding Analytic Functions that Satisfy Certain Values

Tags: complex-analysis

In each of the following cases, determine whether there exists a function $f$, analytic on an open set including the origin, such that $f(1), f(1/2), f(1/3), f(1/4)$ etc. take on the values:

1. $ 1, 0, 1/3, 0, 1/5...$
2. $1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6, 6/7...$

How might one go about doing these sorts of questions?  Is the idea to find a relevant power series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the *non-existence* of a function satisfying one of these, it would be useful to use the theorem that, if $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $z$ and if $f$ vanishes in infinitely many points in every neighbourhood of $z$, then $f$ is identically zero (on the component of its domain containing $z$). Also, sometimes, the obvious corollary you get by applying this to the difference between two analytic functions.

To show *existence*, do try to find an explicit example. Trying a general power series seems too difficult to do in general.

Comment: Interesting!  So clearly 1 cannot exist as it vanishes at infinitely many points.  As for finding examples, is it a matter of thinking about what series result in similar values?  For example $n/n+1$ for 2?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I suppose you meant $n/(n+1)$. But try to express that in terms of $z=1/n$.